# uploading files not given a temp name

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a PHP script that handles uploaded files. It's typically working fine, but I'm occasionally getting upload errors. when I check the `$_FILES` array, this is what I can see:

File that has failed:

```
Array ( [Filedata] => Array (
      [name] => cbj2_web.pdf 
      [type] => 
      [tmp_name] => 
      [error] => 1 
      [size] => 0 ) )
```

File that has worked:

```
Array ( [Filedata] => Array ( 
        [name] => tick.png 
        [type] => application/octet-stream 
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpL8oYLc 
        [error] => 0 
        [size] => 1108 ) )
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong or how to even pinpoint it. This is the at the first step of processing the file, so I don't have any code that's doing anything with the file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe by noticing one has error 0 and the other error 1 ;)

Comment: yes, as Tim pointed out below. I'd missed what the error meant and how to solve :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php:

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

So you need to edit your php.ini file to increase the upload_max_filesize value to a higher value.

Comment: Normally one might criticize the poster for not looking up the error code, but I know that if I saw "error = 0" and "error = 1" I'd just assume that it was a binary parameter...

Comment: that is what i did. :) thanks for giving the benefit of a doubt

Answer (score 5):

You're getting an `error` of `1`.  This is `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`.

From http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php:

> The uploaded file exceeds the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in php.ini.